# Designing two classes that have slightly different data

Tags: c#

Let's say my first class has a public property that returns the headers of a file to be exported.  For example:

```
private readonly List<string> fileHeaders = new List<string>
{
    "Last Name", 
    "First Name", 
    "Middle Name", 
    "Suffix", 
    "Degree",           
};

public List<string> FileHeaders
{
    get { return fileHeaders; }
}
```

Now I have a `class B` that only difference in the file headers it exports is that it has one more column header to export for example a Address column.

What is a good object oriented design that can do this?

Comment: Make `fileHeaders` be a protected member of a base class. Have both classes inherit from the base class but change `fileHeaders`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer this solution with an interface and abstract base class that enforces the implementation in derived classes.

This covers the SOLID open-closed principle

```
public interface IFileHeaders
{
    IList<string> GetFileHeaders();
}

public abstract class FileHeaderBase : IFileHeaders
{
    protected abstract IList<string> FileHeaders { get; }

    public IList<string> GetFileHeaders() => FileHeaders;
}
```

This covers a basic implementation:

```
public class FileHeaderList1 : FileHeaderBase
{
    private readonly IList<string> _fileHeaders = new List<string>
    {
        "Last Name" ,
        "First Name" ,
        "Middle Name" ,
        "Suffix" ,
        "Degree" ,
    };

    protected override IList<string> FileHeaders => _fileHeaders;        
}
```

This covers lazy loading:

```
public class FileHeaderList2 : FileHeaderBase
{
    private IList<string> _fileHeaders;

    protected override IList<string> FileHeaders
    {
        get
        {
            if ( _fileHeaders == null )
            {
                _fileHeaders = new List<string>
                {
                    "Address" ,
                };
            }
            return _fileHeaders;
        }
    }
}
```

This covers dependency injection:

```
public class FileHeaderList3 : FileHeaderBase
{
    private readonly IList<string> _fileHeaders;

    public FileHeaderList3( IList<string> fileHeaders )
    {
        _fileHeaders = fileHeaders;
    }

    protected override IList<string> FileHeaders => _fileHeaders;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make `fileHeaders` a protected member of a base class. Something like:

```
public class Base
{
    protected List<string> fileHeaders;
    public List<string> FileHeaders
    {
        get
        {
            return fileHeaders;
        }
    }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public A()
    {
        fileHeaders = new List<string>
        {"Last Name", "First Name", "Middle Name", "Suffix", "Degree"};
    }
}

public class B : Base
{
    public B()
    {
        fileHeaders = new List<string>
        {"Last Name", "First Name", "Middle Name", "Suffix", "Degree", "Something Else"};
    }
}
```

You could also, if it makes sense (semantically), just have `A` be the base class and have `B` inherit if, for example, it was just a case of `B` has one more column. So something like:

```
public class A
{
    protected readonly List<string> fileHeaders = new List<string>
    {
        "Last Name", "First Name", "Middle Name", "Suffix", "Degree", 
    };

    public List<string> FileHeaders
    {
        get
        {
            return fileHeaders;
        }
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        fileHeaders.Add("Something Else");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since both instances differ only in data, why not create only one class with the list as member and read only property (as above) and initialise it with a parameter in the constructor? No Need for different classes.